# Design for real time aggregations performed on SQL Server transactional data

Tags: c#, sql-server, mapreduce

I have a .NET application firing events and storing tick data in SQL Server.  The transactional data is about 5 GB a day.  For reasons related to the data source, I can only with difficulty modify the .NET application that is processing the events to perform aggregations.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to, in real time and preferably using C# (though I know Python too) ways to automatically aggregate the data in real time.

Does anyone have any ideas about this?  I've thought about map reduce but seems like there would be a delay.  I really would like to avoid building out the .NET application because I can't use Visual Studio to debug.

Comment: This is broad. What kind of data, how much aggregation, how complex, how much historical are you working with, etc.

Comment: Tick data, need to perform some calculations to build features for machine learning consumption.  Those features would be stored in a summary table in the same database.  The calculations are not complex but might be based on people's needs.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by using C# but not through the .NET application? You mean like a CLR procedure in Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

How real time do you need?  The obvious solution is to run a job every minute or so to aggregate the latest detail data and load it into a summary table.

You could also use an [Indexed View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) or even a trigger to maintain the aggregates as data is loaded.

Comment: I need it to the millisecond.  I thought of a trigger but was concerned that would impact write speeds.

Comment: Both solutions will have some impact on write speeds.  For an additive aggregate you have to read the aggregate row with a U lock, and add the inserted value and subtract the deleted value.  This will serialize writes to the group, slowing down parallel writes to the table.